# Dynamically changing background color for splash screens

Tags: java, android

I am using the following article to make a splash screen for my app (without doing an activity for it):

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

It works fine. Though, I want to change the background color based on a `SharedPreferences` value. I know I cannot directly change the xml background color value. So, I want to know if there is an alternative way to set the background color or map it to a `SharedPrefences` value.

Thank you.

Edit: I want to avoid creating a new activity for splash screen. To clarify on what I am currently using. I have:

```
android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
```

set on application theme on manifest. Then, on MainActivity I use:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

Comment: sorry, but what you mean by without doing an activity for it !!

Comment: do you want to set the splash color via shared preferences ? or you want to set several colors for the splash screen and make them alternate in loading ?

Comment: @Moustaf EL-Saghier, I have skipped the splash activity part in that tutorial and doing the splash screen on MainActivity.

Comment: @Sami you have to create new activity for it so that you can control in the splash by code.

Comment: @Badran, I want to set the splash screen color based on SharedPreferences. Like for example I allow people to change the background of my app dynamically and I want the splash screen background to match it.

Comment: okay , I will write you the implementation

Comment: You should really add the details of that splash screen implementation to the question. Otherwise, you're going to get more answers that don't really operate as that does.

Comment: Done check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared Preferences implementation:

```
private SharedPreferences pref;
```

then load it

```
pref = this.getSharedPreferences("myAppPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

now if the user changes the color , you have to save it like this

```
pref.edit().putString("splashColor","the new color hex here ex: #FFFFFF").commit();
```

and when the user reopen now(or opens for the first time) you have to load it from prefs and show it :

```
String color= pref.getString("splashColor","your default color here ex : #000000");
```

in variable color there will be your color hex code

Now in **splash_activity.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in **SplashActivity.java** in on create:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity.xml);
    mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.root);
    pref = this.getSharedPreferences("myAppPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String color = pref.getString("splashColor","your default color here ex : #000000");
    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int Delay = 3000; // choose ur own delay

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    },Delay);
```

**NOTE**: use this when you want to save or change the color :  `pref.edit().putString("splashColor","the new color hex here ex: #FFFFFF").commit();`

Comment: Thank you for the effort, @Badran. I really appreciate it. Though, my question is not on how to use the SharedPreferences. My question is how I can map the stored preference into the splash screen background

Comment: oh, i will edit my answer then , but you have to create an activity

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Badran. I am trying to avoid creating an activity just for a splash screen. If I do not get any alternative answer, I will accept yours.

Comment: you are most welcome ! are you using Relative layout ? if yes I have another also without creating another activity

Comment: I am using CoordinatorLayout wrapped inside ConstraintLayout wrapped inside DrawerLayout.